# Getting all changed files from a certain date from a VS project or VSS?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-sourcesafe

Is there a utlity or other means to easily pull all changed fiels from a VS ASP.NET project or from the associated VSS store for that poroject fro ma given date and have it maintain the folder structure and dump it to a seperate folder from the dev version for deployment purposes?  Want to be able to easily grab the chanegs so we can push them over to a test server to merge with the previous version without doing a full copy of the source.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking for:

Using SourceSafe: Get by Date
http://brennan.offwhite.net/mtblog/archives/000282.html

Comment: That may be the only option.  Even somethig nthat would pull it from the local dev folder would be fine, and jsut create the duplciate structure for the files changed sicne X.